Is it correct to insert Scaffold into SafeArea
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: const Column(
          children: [],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


In our learning process, we're encountering certain issues. Is it possible to place things on top of the Scaffold?

It is possible wrap your Scaffold with a SafeArea, but you will see a black area at the top of your screen because that area is not part of Scaffold, which does some basic Material Design styling for you out of the box.
In terms of whether it is correct or not, generally you want to put everything inside your Scaffold to take advantage of the builit-in styling.
